# Scandinavian characters æ, ø, å escaped incorrectly

Tags: objective-c, macos, utf8-decode

My program interfaces with servers in other countries and regularly needs to handle URLs containing foreign characters. This works fine until we consider Scandinavian characters such as `æ`, `ø`, and `å`. When I receive a URL, I decode it as follows:

```
-(NSString*)urlDECODE:(NSString*)string
{
    NSString*   s = [string stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    return (s)?s:string;
}
```

This fails to properly decode these characters, however:

```
filename: æøåa.rtf
input: %C3%83%C2%A6%C3%83%C2%B8a%C3%8C%C2%8Aa.rtf
output: Ã¦Ã¸aÌa.rtf
```

EDIT: This is the encoding function:

```
NSString * URLEncode(NSString * url)
{
    NSString* out = nil;
    @try
    {
        NSLog(@"BEFORE=%@",url);
        out = [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"AFTER=%@",out);
    }
    @catch (NSException * e)
    {
        NSLog(@"Encoding error: %@", e);
    }

return out;
}
```

Comment: how are you generating the output messages?

Comment: have you tried with `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`.

Comment: Also, are you sure the input (the `string` variable) is correct?

Comment: @sergio `NSLog(@"Decoded=%@", strFilename);`

Comment: @Monolo I am sending the file myself, editing the question to show my encode code.

Comment: Normally you don't need to use `@try/@catch` in Obj-C.

Comment: @KennyTM The `@try/@catch` is existing legacy code within the program, but good to know. I'll see if I can just nip that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your original URL is already mistakenly encoded in UTF-8.

```
"Ã¦Ã¸aÌŠa.rtf" == "\xc3\xa6\xc3\xb8a\xcc\x8aa.rtf"
               == "æ"      "ø"    "a\u030a" "a.rtf"  // in UTF-8
               == "æøåa.rtf"
```

Please check the constructed NSString passed to URLEncode(). The other code you've shown are correct (except that it's rare to handle exceptions in Objective-C).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. It turns out there was a bug that was rendering my UTF-8 encoded strings into ASCII, and then a secondary encode was preformed due to the UTF-8 encoding seeming to have not previously occurred.